# Syntax error on sqlite when updating table

Tags: sqlite

I'm pulling data from my energy provider as a rawTable and then would like to perform some calculations to place the data in an easier way to search as well as to do calculations.

The data I receive from the energy supplier lands in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "rawData" (
    "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "consumption"   REAL NOT NULL,
    "startTime" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "endTime"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

I then created this table to hold the data I want per day.

```
CREATE TABLE "structuredData" (
    "rowID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Year"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Month" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Day"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "PeakConsumption"   REAL,
    "OffPeakConsumptioon"   REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY("rowID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

To get the offpeak consumption from the rawData, I run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO structuredData (Year, Month, Day, OffPeakConsumptioon)
SELECT strftime('%d', startTime) as valDay,
strftime('%m', startTime) as valMonth,
strftime('%Y', startTime) as valYear,
SUM(consumption) as valTotalDay
FROM rawData
WHERE
strftime('%Y', startTime)>='2021'
AND (strftime('%H:%M:%S',startTime) >= "00:30:00"
AND strftime('%H:%M:%S',startTime) < "04:30:00")
GROUP BY valYear, valMonth, valDay ;
```

Then I need to essentially do the same to the Peak Consumption and came up with this query:

```
UPDATE structuredData 
SET PeakConsumption = daily.amt
FROM (SELECT SUM(consumption) as amt, strftime('%d', startTime) as valDay,  strftime('%m', startTime) as valMonth,  strftime('%Y', startTime) as valYear
                FROM rawData
                WHERE   strftime('%Y', startTime)>='2021'
                AND (strftime('%H:%M:%S',startTime) >= "00:00:00" AND strftime('%H:%M:%S',endTime) <= "00:30:00"
                OR strftime('%H:%M:%S',startTime) >= "04:30:00" AND strftime('%H:%M:%S',endTime) <="23:30:00")
                GROUP BY valYear, valMonth, valDay) AS daily
 WHERE structuredData.Day = daily.valDay
 and structuredData.Month = daily.valMonth
 and structuredData.Year = daily.valYear;
```

However, this tells me there's an error.

Execution finished with errors.
Result: near "FROM": syntax error
At line 1:
UPDATE structuredData
SET PeakConsumption = 1
FROM

Any ideas where I may be messing up??

Comment: For the UPDATE...FROM syntax you need SQLite 3.33.0+. Check your version.

Comment: I'm on Macosx and the version that pops up in the terminal is SQLite version 3.36.0 2021-06-18 18:58:49

Comment: Then your code should work. I still believe that you are executing the query on a version of SQLite prior to 3.33.0

Comment: I'm using DB Browser for SQLite where I get this error. Running the command as a .sql file gives me no output, but no change to the database either.

Comment: Your code in DB Browser for SQLite 3.12.2 runs without errors.

Comment: Right. It was DB Browser's issue then. :( However, the query doesn't change any row in the table.

Comment: For this I can't help if you don't provide sample data and expected results so that you clarify what you want.

Comment: How can I add some data to display here? The rawData stores kWh values in 30 minute intervals. My off peak consumption runs from 00:30:00 to 04:30:00. In my first query, I calculate the total consumption during this interval. At the same time, I break the timestamp into 3 different fields (month, day, year). I then want to run a separate query to fill in the quantity of kWh in the peak hours per day. The query that calculates the peak consumption per day works, it's then updating the database that isn't working.

Comment: You can create a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 and paste the link here or paste sample data in tabular format as text and not images inside your question.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=abe1a2a57dd8348d7c206998fe8d08c3    This is a sample of the rawData

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=95adbb0e20c45b2861d0838117838095   This is a sample of the result of my query to calculate off peak consumption

Comment: I'm comparing a string to a number, I think.

Comment: More than that you are inserting year values in the day column and day values in the year column in the table structuredData